# extract data from PHP json to use in android

Tags: java, android, arrays, json, string

I'm using this code to fetch some data from PHP file and extract some data into my android application.
This code extract name, price and availability for each product and put each one in an String. 
Now I need to have array of the product in java which that is included name,price and availability for each product and name them product1 product2 product3 so I'll be able to write rest of my code based on that.
How can I do that ?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private String jsonResult;
    private String url = "xxxx/get_all_products.php";
    private ListView listView;

    private static final String TAG_PRODUCTS = "products";
    private static final String TAG_PID = "pid";
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
    private static final String TAG_PRICE = "price";
    private static final String TAG_FOUND = "found";
    private static final String TAG_DESCRIPTION = "description";

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        productList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
                String selval = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name)).getText().toString();
                String selval1 = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.price)).getText().toString();
                String selval2 = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.found)).getText().toString();
                // Also I've found a solution on SO that a guy solved this problem doing soemthing like this :
                // TextView txt = (TextView) parent.getChildAt(position - listview.firstVisiblePosition()).findViewById(R.id.sometextview);
                // String keyword = txt.getText().toString();
                Intent intnt = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SingleListItem.class);
                intnt.putExtra("selval", selval);
                intnt.putExtra("selval1", selval1);
                intnt.putExtra("selval2", selval2);

                startActivity(intnt);
 }
    });

        accessWebService();

    }

    // Async Task to access the web
    private class JsonReadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(params[0]);
            try {
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                jsonResult = inputStreamToString(
                        response.getEntity().getContent()).toString();
            }

            catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        private StringBuilder inputStreamToString(InputStream is) {
            String rLine = "";
            StringBuilder answer = new StringBuilder();
            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

            try {
                while ((rLine = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                    answer.append(rLine);
                }
            }

            catch (IOException e) {
                // e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Error..." + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            return answer;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            ListDrwaer();
        }
    }// end async task

    public void accessWebService() {
        JsonReadTask task = new JsonReadTask();
        // passes values for the urls string array
        task.execute(new String[]{url});
    }

    // build hash set for list view
    public void ListDrwaer() {
        List<Map<String, String>> productList = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();

        try {
            JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(jsonResult);
            JSONArray jsonMainNode = jsonResponse.optJSONArray("products");

            for (int i = 0; i < jsonMainNode.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jsonChildNode = jsonMainNode.getJSONObject(i);
                String name = jsonChildNode.optString("name");
                String price = jsonChildNode.optString("price");
                    String found = jsonChildNode.optString("found");
                //    String outPut = name + "-" + number;
           //     String outPut = name + "-" + price + "-" + found;
           //     productList.add(createProduct("products", outPut));
                HashMap<String, String> product = new HashMap<String, String>();

                product.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                product.put(TAG_FOUND, found);
                product.put(TAG_PRICE, price);

               productList.add(product);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error" + e.toString(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        SimpleAdapter simpleAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, productList,
                R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TAG_NAME, TAG_PRICE,
                TAG_FOUND }, new int[] { R.id.name,
                R.id.price, R.id.found });
        listView.setAdapter(simpleAdapter);

        }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

its very simple, by using this code outside of the for loop

```
JSONObject pro1 = jsonMainNode.getJSONObject(0);
```